# Text import error

Tags: mysql, database

Good Day

I have created a bat file to import a text file to my MySQL database and it looks as follows:

```
    sqlcmd /user root /pass password /db "MyDB" /command "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE TG_Orders FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

My problem is that I cannot get the "Treat consecutive delimiters as one" to work...

How would I add that?

Comment: Is `sqlcmd` the name of your .bat file or an executable file for MySQL? If the former, we need to see the contents of it. If the latter, I don't think that MySQL uses `sqlcmd` - MSSQL does but with different switches. Of course, I'm used to MySQL on Linux  so if there's a version for when it's running on Windows then I apologize now.

Comment: Hi, sqlcmd is an .exe file that runs on windows to access the mysql database.

Comment: So is `sqlcmd.exe` a custom written application or one supplied by MySQL? I can find no reference to it in the MySQL documentation. If it's custom written then we can't really help - the whole problem could be caused by that application and we don't have the application to try out. I think the problem may be that your SQL query is being truncated prematurely by the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` bit. Try escaping the `"`  so you end up with `ENCLOSED BY '\"'` and see if that helps

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. The problem is with the comma. I have certain cells with data that includes a comma in the phrase eg. B121,565 and it moves everything after the comma into a column. With the "Tread consecutive delimiters as one" option it skips those commas inside a "CELL".

Comment: Does the SQL that you're using to import the file work correctly when performed directly on the server in an SQL session? If it does then the error lies in the command line version you're using. Again, I still suspect the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` bit: you're using a '"' at the start of the SQL but the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` is ending it and teh `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"` is never reached. Without seeing any errors that you're getting then there's not a lot anyone (well, I) can do for you.

Comment: Please! Close this question! you asked it almost 12 months ago and it is just sitting here festering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we have actually got to the real crux of the problem, this is **not** a consecutive delimiter problem - it's a CSV file format problem.

If your CSV file contains fields like `B121,535` and they are not enclosed within quote marks of some kind *and* your delimeter is `,` then no amount of SQL jiggery-pokery will sort out your problem. Un-quoted fields with commas like this will **always** be interpreted as two separate fields **unless** enclosed within quote marks.

Post a sample line from the CSV file which is causing problems and we can diagnose further. Failing that, export the data from the initial system again making sure that the formatting is correct (either enclose everything in speech marks or just string fields)

Finally, are you sure that your database is MySQL based and not Microsoft SQL? The only references to `SQLCMD.EXE` I can find all point to Microsoft sites in relation to SQL Server Express but, even then, it has a different option structure (`-U` for user rather than `/user`). If this is the case you could have saved a lot of hassle by putting the correct information tags. If not then I would say that `SQLCMD.EXE` is a custom written application from somewhere and the problem could all stem from that. If that is the case then we can't help if the CSV formatting is correct - you're on your own

Comment: So, any progress on this or are you just going to let this sit here for eternity?

Comment: Yup. Just going to let this question sit here and fester. For pity sake, close this question down or ask for it to be deleted. It's like a bad smell in a small space

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry for keeping this open till now. The problem was on the client side and the CSV file was incorrect. This is fix..Thanks for the help